# Why did I just lose 25 rep randomly?

Tags: support, reputation

On the Japanese Stack Exchange in some older browser tabs, I see that I have 3870 rep:

[image: 3,870 reputation 2 gold badges 11 silver badges 33 bronze badges]

But if I refresh, it shows that I have 3845 rep. I don't see any changes in the reputation tab.

[image: 0 today | There were no net reputation changes on this day]

So I'm wondering what happened.

Comment: Do you have, "Show removed posts" checked at the bottom?

Comment: @fbueckert I didn't but when I checked it and refreshed the page, there was no difference on the first page I'm looking at.

Comment: First guess is that you answered a question that the asker upvoted and accepted.  And then it was deleted for some reason.  Show removed posts should show that, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A user upvoted and accepted one of your answers, and then retracted both of those votes. When both the vote and unvote occur on the same day, they get collapsed in the reputation history and you don't see them, which is why you see the day appear as a 0-change with that message when there are no other events that day.

Comment: So, if I were to get reputation change today from something else, I should be able to see the specific events?

Comment: @Ringil you should, unless, as animuson pointed out, that event was reversed in the same day (by an un-accept, un-upvote, un-downvote, etc.)